# How would you create an ASP.NET MVC EditorTemplate that disables field if data is present?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't have a lot of experience writing EditorTemplates, the one I've written was to apply a css class to a textarea (I find it odd that the EditorFor method doesn't have an overload for applying HTML attributes).

I'm trying to create a form, that has several fields that - if there is already data present (in the viewdata model) - that those fields would remain in the form, but be disabled so visitors cannot change them... leaving the open fields active to change.

I wish to use the `HTML.EditorFor(model => model.property)` syntax, is it possible to create an EditorTemplate that does what I described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that should get you started.  Inside the editor template you would check if the value of the model is empty or null and if so pass in a custom dictionary of HtmlAttributes to the TextBox or area template.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>
<%
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model))
    {
        htmlAttributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
    }
%>
<%: Html.TextBox("Name", Model, htmlAttributes)%>
```

Comment: See, I knew it was something along those lines! Thanks a ton Michael, really appreciate the quick answer.

Comment: correct answer, but i'd actually prefer to do this via a customer HTML helper, e.g `Html.DisableableTextBoxFor(model => model.FieldName)`. Which does the above code **in code**, as opposed to UI code soup. Still, the end result is the same.

Comment: That's what I like about coding there is always an improvement to make.  Thanks RPM1984